# SQL join left get MAX(date)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

i have these tables :

- notice

  - id INT
  - cdate DATETIME
  - ...
- theme

  - id
  - name
- notice_theme

  - id_notice
  - id_theme

I want to get the latest notices for each theme.

```
SELECT id_theme, n.id
FROM notice_theme
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, cdate
    FROM notice
    ORDER BY cdate DESC
) AS n ON notice_theme.id_notice = n.id
GROUP BY id_theme
```

The result is not good. An idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your MAX(date)?

Comment: There's no guarantees that the ORDER BY of a joined table will be preserved. Put the ORDER BY in the outer select.

Comment: You need to add Max(n.cdate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are so many ways to solve this but I'm used to do it this way. An extra subquery is needed to separately calculate the latest `cDate` for every `ID`.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    theme a
        INNER JOIN notice_theme b
            ON a.ID = b.id_theme
        INNER JOIN  notice c
            ON b.id_notice = c.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.id_theme, MAX(b.DATE_CREATE) max_date
            FROM    notice_theme a
                    INNER JOIN notice b
                        ON a.ID_Notice = b.ID
            GROUP   BY a.id_theme
        ) d ON  b.id_theme = d.id_theme AND
                c.DATE_CREATE = d.max_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab90c9/7)

Comment: Thanks for answer, with your query (@JW) :  

> id_theme----id_notice----date_create  
> 2-----------2------------2013-03-31 09:18:21  
> 4-----------2------------2013-03-31 09:18:21  
> 1-----------7------------2013-03-31 23:27:28  
> 2-----------7------------2013-03-31 23:27:28  
> 4-----------11-----------2013-02-16 04:40:21  
> 5-----------12-----------2013-02-05 20:18:21  
> 4-----------13-----------2013-03-31 23:27:28  
> 2-----------14-----------2013-03-15 20:18:21  

And with a GROUP BY a.id, I have the same problem with my query :/

Comment: can you give sample records with your deired result?

Comment: when problems like this, always add sample records with your desired result so we can visualized more on the problem `:)`